# Правильно ли поставлены знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

"Спасибо!" - впервые слышу это слово, сказанное так искренне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки поставлены вполне нормально

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, все верно.